# How to share memory over long chain of method calls?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, aop

**I need to figure out a way to save and log a method request and response conditionally, with the condition being the latency of the top-level method crossing the p50 latency.** The call visualization is as follows:

```
topLevel() -> method1() -> method2() -> ... -> makeRequest()
```

In makeRequest is where the request and response to that request are that I need to log.

But I'll only know if I need to actually log those at some point on the way back up the call stack - if topLevel method is taking too long.

So to me, the only option is to save the request and response in makeRequest no matter what and make that available to the topLevel method. The topLevel method will check if latency is above p50 and conditionally log the request and response.

This all leads to the titular question: **How to share memory over long chain of method calls?**

I don't want to be passing objects back through multiple method calls, polluting function signatures.

**What is the best pattern for this? Maybe using a local cache to save the request and response and then retrieving it in topLevel? Is there an aspect oriented approach to solving this?**

Comment: Is it an option to build a *containing* object for your data, initialize it in top level, let any method store info in it (including makeRequest) and just pass it along the call chain?

Comment: @SergeBallesta I honestly am trying hard to avoid that because there are so many intermediate method calls and I don't want to add noise to the function signatures. But I guess that is the fall back yes. Just wondering if there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: What if you try session?

Comment: You can use a *container* singleton if you are sure that you will never use this is different threads. If you want to have one object per thread, you will have to store a `ThreadLocal` object in the singleton container.

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have control of the code for the top level and down through `method1` and `method2`, this really isn't so hard.

You just need to pass the request down through the calling chain, and pass back the response.

```
topLevel() -> method1(request) -> method2(request) -> ...
    -> makeRequest(request) { ... return response; }
```

To relate this to a real code example, you can look at how the `jersey` framework works.

Here's an example of a method where the request is injected, and a response is returned.

```
@POST
@Consumes({MediaType.TEXT_XML})
@Produces({TEXT_XML_UTF_8})
public Response resource(@Context HttpServletRequest servletRequest) throws Exception {
    ExternalRequest req = makeRequest(servletRequest.getInputStream());
    ExternalResponse resp = externalGateway.doSomething(req);
    return Response.ok(wrapResponse(resp)).build();
}
```

Although Jersey offers some fancy annotations (`@Context` and so on), there isn't really a distinguishable design pattern here of any significance - you're just passing down the request object and returning a response.

Of course you can also maintain a cache and pass that up the call stack, or really just a wrapper object for a request and a response, but it's very similar to simply passing the request.

Comment: Ok, I was trying to avoid that but it seems like that is actually the most straightforward approach. I'll just pass an object through method calls and store the data there. I don't think there's a need to return anything if I'm just passing an object reference.

Comment: It is the most straight forward for sure, and you avoid all sorts of issues with sessions and threading.

Answer (score 0):

This type of functionality is best done using ThreadLocals. Your `makeRequest` will add the request and response objects into ThreadLocal and then `topLevel` will remove them and log them if needed. Here is an example:

```
public class RequestResponseThreadLocal{

        public static ThreadLocal<Object[]> requestResponseThreadLocal = new ThreadLocal<>();
    }

    public class TopLevel{

        public void topLevel(){
            try{ 
                new Method1().method1();

                Object[] requestResponse = RequestResponseThreadLocal.requestResponseThreadLocal.get();

                System.out.println( requestResponse[0] + " : " + requestResponse[1] );
            }finally{
                //make sure to clean up stuff that was added to ThreadLocal otherwise you will end up with memory leak when using Thread pools
                RequestResponseThreadLocal.requestResponseThreadLocal.remove();
            }
        }
    }

    public class Method1{

        public void method1(){
            new Method2().method2();
        }
    }

    public class Method2{

        public void method2(){
            new MakeRequest().makeRequest();
        }
    }

    public class MakeRequest{

        public void makeRequest(){
            Object request = new Object();
            Object response = new Object();
            RequestResponseThreadLocal.requestResponseThreadLocal.set( new Object[]{request, response} );
        }
    }
```